# Get value of the word when the word is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have text which gets passed to the page. There is also 'special words' which get highlighted by using this `highlight function below`.

It puts it into an `<a>` tag with its class and the style which makes it get highlighted. After this function has run the special words become highlighted and clickable in the text.

So it would do this to the text: `<a class="clickable" style="background-color: yellow;">Hello</a>`. Creates an `<a>`, puts it into a `class` and `styles` it.

The issue I am having now is when I click a word which has been **highlighted**, and has its own `class='clickable'` how can I get what word has been clicked? I need to check which **word** has been clicked in order to query the database and fetch the annotation to the word.

```
highlight = words => {
  const high = document.getElementById('scrollable');
  const paragraph = high.innerHTML.split(' ');
  const res = [];

    paragraph.map(word => {
      let t = word;
      if (words.indexOf(word) > -1) {
        t =
          '<a class="clickable" style="background-color: yellow;">' +
          word +
          '</a>';
        console.log(words.indexOf(word));
      }
      // console.log(words);
      res.push(t);
    });

    high.innerHTML = res.join(' ');
    const elementsToMakeClickable = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'clickable'
    );
    const elementsToMakeClickableArray = Array.from(elementsToMakeClickable);

    elementsToMakeClickableArray.map(element => {
      element.addEventListener('click', this.viewAnnotation.bind(this));
    });
}
```

To save some time logs:
`console.log(words);` will return the three special words.
`console.log(words.indexOf(word));` will return each word as 0,1 or 2 because obviously we are console.logging the `index`.

The special words from the database are: `Hello`, `Lorem` and `dolor`. Not that it should help but I have included it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly... As you already listen to the `click`-event for each `a.clickable`-element, I assume that your problem is the *retrieval*-part to get the `word`?

In the `event`-hander, the current element is added to the `event`-object as `target`. To retrieve the html/text contents one could use this element in conjunction with the `textContent`/`innerText`/`innerHTML` property:

```
viewAnnotation(e) {
  const word = e.target.textContent.trim()

  // Do something with `word`
}
```

Comment: Quick, easy and straightforward. Many thanks to your Sir. This is the solution to the question, I will accept it as an answer as soon the timer is up.

Comment: @Andrew Great to hear that this did the trick for you. Thanks for your feedback :)